# Bash if string check

Tags: bash

I am evaluating following following expression. And it always evaluates to true even if CMD is START or STARTED. Am I doing something wrong?

```
if [ "$CMD"="START" ]; then
    echo fi
fi
```

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try spaces

```
if [ "$CMD" = "START" ] ; then
     echo fi
fi
```

Comment: To be perfect it needs `[ ]` turned into `[[ ]]` to make sure it's evaluated by bash itself :)

Comment: Can you give more context, if you think it always false, then, probably, something's wrong with your `$CMD`.

Comment: I am extracting the command string using following expression CMD=`grep -i "CMD" $TPMSTATUS | cut -d":" -f2` where TPMSTATUS contains the string CMD and its value separated by :

Comment: So what is in "CMD"?  It probably isn't what you think.  Try `echo "x$CMDx"` to see if you're getting spaces or something before or after.

Comment: Found the problem mapping was CMD : "START", but when I remove the double quotes, it worked

Comment: Removing double quotes is generally not a good idea, it will change the meaning in case of empty string.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker so how can I initiate CMD in mapping in my status file , so that comparison is successful

Comment: I have no idea what your status file looks like, @siri.

Comment: Works for me without the quotes as well, as in
`if [ $native = yes ]; then echo Yes; fi`
on Cygwin bash, as it should.

Comment: @Sven, try with `$native` equal to empty string?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have spaces around the `=`.

```
#CMD="STARTED"
#if [ "$CMD" = "START" ] ; then echo fi; fi
#CMD="START"
#if [ "$CMD" = "START" ] ; then echo fi; fi
fi
#
```

Comment: @siri, then you are doing something different from what you say you're doing, because that's cut and pasted from my shell.

Answer (score 1):

From http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_02.html:

> ```
>   [] vs. [[]]
> ```
>
> Contrary to [, [[ prevents word splitting of variable values. So, if
>   VAR="var with spaces", you do not need to double quote $VAR in a test
>   - eventhough using quotes remains a good habit. Also, [[ prevents pathname expansion, so literal strings with wildcards do not try to
>   expand to filenames. Using [[, == and != interpret strings to the
>   right as shell glob patterns to be matched against the value to the
>   left, for instance: [[ "value" == val* ]].

So, try:

```
if [[ "$CMD" == "START" ]]; then
    echo "fi"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add spaces:

```
if [ "$CMD" == "START" ]; then
...
fi
```

Comment: -eq is for int and numer types only.  Not strings.

Comment: -eq is arithmetic, not for strings.